# Unprocessable Entity while using Shopify library

Tags: php, cakephp, semantics, shopify

I'm using Shopify CakePHP library and when I want to create the recurring payments I keep getting error "Unprocessable Entity".

Same error is occurring for two similar libraries: [First](http://gh.codehum.com/miumoin/ohShopify.php), [Second](https://github.com/sandeepshetty/shopify.php)

Error is occuring in these section:

```
// Create a new recurring charge
        $charge = array
        (
            "recurring_application_charge"=>array
            (
                "price"=>1.0,
                "name"=>"Super Duper Plan",
                "return_url"=>"http://super-duper.shopifyapps.com",
                "test"=>true
            )
        );

        try
        {
            $recurring_application_charge = $sc->call('POST', '/admin/recurring_application_charges.json', $charge);

            // API call limit helpers
            echo $sc->callsMade(); // 2
            echo $sc->callsLeft(); // 498
            echo $sc->callLimit(); // 500

        }
        catch (ShopifyApiException $e)
        {
            debug($e->getMessage()); // Error
        }
```

Error that I'm getting is number **422** which has this description : *The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors.*
That means that something inside an array is wrong. Can you tell me what could be the problem in here?

***Note***: `$charge` section was copy/paste from Shopify Billing API documentation

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using https://github.com/isaacbowen/shopify-cakephp why are you constructing and performing the request manually? You should be able to use the helpers that it creates, I see a ShopifyRecurringApplicationCharge class in the code. I'm definitely no php expert but I'm not sure your request is going to encode your payload to json correctly is it?